# I need To Add window.onresize code to this javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function getUrlVars() {
 var vars = {};
 var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
  vars[key] = value;
});
 return vars;
}
var video = getUrlVars()["v"];
var width=getUrlVars()["w"];
var height=getUrlVars()["h"];
document.write('<iframe src="https:xxx.com?id='+video+'" id="iframe" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" Scrolling="no" height="+height+"></iframe>');
//]]>
</script>
```

in the above code i want to add window.onresie event if i add a fuction it is not working please help me.

Comment: Sorry, not clicking on an unknown link just because you tell me to. What is your code like when you add the function? In which way *exactly* is it not working? Is there an error message? Does it silently ignore your resizes? Does it drink all of your tomato soup out of your fridge?

Comment: There is risk associated with clicking on your potentially malicious link. No one should have to leave the site to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use something simple like the following:

### http://jsfiddle.net/Godisgood/xbm4feoy/

You can incorporate this JS into your current code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function myFunction() {
var w = window.outerWidth;
var h = window.outerHeight;
var txt = "Window size: width=" + w + ", height=" + h;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
function getUrlVars() {
 var vars = {};
 var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
  vars[key] = value;
});
 return vars;
}
var video = getUrlVars()["v"];
var width=getUrlVars()["w"];
var height=getUrlVars()["h"];
document.write('<iframe src="https:xxx.com?id='+video+'" id="iframe" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" Scrolling="no" height="+height+"></iframe>');
//]]>
</script>
```

Hope this helps!